# Google Forms - Add unique identifier to submissions - not using an array formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I previously used an array formula to assign a unique ID to new form submissions; but with 27 columns and over 5000 rows of data, the cost to run the array formula interferes with my onformsubmit to send out a custom email to a subset of people blocking it from sending out emails.

I'm trying to assign the value "Txxxxxx" where xxxxxx is the next number of the submissions in Column 22, i.e. T05000 or T00100

I have no idea on how to write the code to do this, anyone have any ideas?  Would I have to trigger it with an onformsubmit?  Would that interfere with the onformsubmit I already have to send out emails?

[image: Sample location of column to add unique id]

Comment: Unfortunately, from `I'm trying to assign the value "Txxxxxx" where xxxxxx is the next number of the submissions in Column 22, i.e. T05000 or T00100`, I cannot understand about your goal. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample input and output situation as the images?

Comment: When a new form submission is submitted, I am looking to assign it a new # that starts with T, as in T00100, the next entry, when submitted would be T00101, T001002, etc....

Comment: "I'm trying to assign the value"
Where to assign? Please show the desired result using a picture or a screenshot.

Comment: Added in original post, thank you for your time

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed your replying just now. I apologize for this. From your updated question, I proposed a sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put a counter value when the Google form is submitted.
- In your situation, the counter value is put to the column "V" as the format like `T001216` and `T001217`.

  - When the previous counter is `T001217`, when the Google form is submitted, you want to put the value of `T001218` to the column "V" of the submitted row.

In this case, I would like to propose the following sample script. In this sample script, the method of `autoFill` in Class Range is used.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the container-bound script of Google Spreadsheet that the value is submitted from Google form. And [please install the OnSubmit trigger to the function of `onSubmit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). By this, when the Google form is submitted, the value like `T01218` is added to the column "V".

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  const initialValue = "T001216"; // This is the initial value at the row 2.
  const counterColumn = 22; // 22 is the column "V".

  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (range.rowStart == 2) {
    sheet.getRange(2, counterColumn).setValue(initialValue);
    return;
  }
  const previousRange = sheet.getRange(2, counterColumn, range.rowStart - 2);
  previousRange.autoFill(previousRange.offset(0, 0, range.rowStart - 1), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
}
```

- In this sample script, when the 1st value is submitted of Google form, the value of `initialValue` is used as the initial value. In this sample script, the value of `T001216` is used because of your sample image.

#### Note:

- **This sample script is run by the installable OnSubmite trigger, when the Google form is submitted. So, when you directly run the function of `onSubmit` at the script editor, an error like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined` occurs. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [autoFill(destination, series)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#autofilldestination,-series)

Comment: Thank you, I will test this today; but I have a question. I already have an OnSubmit function that runs and sends out an email, will these two attempting to run on submit clash and error out ?

Comment: @JasonG Thank you for replying. About your new question of `but I have a question. I already have an OnSubmit function that runs and sends out an email, will these two attempting to run on submit clash and error out ?`, although I'm not sure about your actual situation, in that case, how about using LockService? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)

Comment: Is there some code to introduce that would delay the running of one script so that the Email one goes out AFTER the code to assign a Unique ID?

Comment: @JasonG Thank you for replying. I think that your `Is there some code to introduce that would delay the running of one script so that the Email one goes out AFTER the code to assign a Unique ID?` is different from [your this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67020779). And, from your replying, I cannot still understand whether my answer could resolve your this question. I apologize for this. So, at first, I would like to propose to resolve your 1st question. If you can cooperate to resolve your this question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your this question?

Comment: The code you provided does add a value; but it adds it to every row in the sheet, even the blank ones under the last submitted, which technically your solution does solve my question; but how do i get it to assign a unique ID to JUST the submitted lines and not the blank ?

Comment: @JasonG Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation from `but it adds it to every row in the sheet, even the blank ones under the last submitted, which technically your solution does solve my question; but how do i get it to assign a unique ID to JUST the submitted lines and not the blank ?`.

Comment: @JasonG Although I can see your situation from your sample image, I cannot understand about your replying from the image. I deeply apologize for my poor understanding. In order to correctly understand about it, can I ask you about the detail of your current situation? By this, I would like to try to understand it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Comment: the code you provided makes a number in every cell, even the blank ones.  I am trying to assign a number to only lines with data.

Comment: @JasonG Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal from your replying. I apologize for this. But I would like to try to understand it and support you. So, in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you post it as new question by including more sample situations? By this, I would like to think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve it?