# Google Form click "Submit", sequentual ID#

Tags: google-sheets

[Google Froms]
I have a Google Form that I want to attach an ID number to in the Google Sheet that is sequenced by "1" starting with a unique number. In this case the Number is "95000" and the column referenced is "K".

Should this be done in the Form or within the Sheet?

rivers

Comment: This is a very common question: would you please summarise your research before posting this question, and explain why none of the questions that you saw would apply to your scenario. Related question: [Google Forms - Add unique identifier to submissions - not using an array formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67041014/1330560), [How to assign a unique ID to a google form input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28682916/1330560)